# Implementing deque tailored to my usecase

Tags: c++, deque

I have been trying to implement a deque using two vector; for pushing from front and back respectively. To get the elements in order I would iterate back vector with normal iterator and front vector with reverse iterator. std :: deque is slow and I don't need it's complete functionality. So, I am trying to make my own class to speed up execution.

Everything was working fine unless I realized I also need to acess and pop elements from back/front until queue becomes empty. In such a case I'll need to switch the back vector from vector popping from back and from front to back while popping from front.

Even that I can do, but then in some cases after switching from back vector to front I might need to add more element from back, now they should go into the front vector. I tried to tweak the code but everyting is messing up and I just can't come up with a nice logic that could work. I need some suggestions and ideas. Please help. Here's the code.

```
class Deque{
public:
        vector<int> front;
        vector<int> back;
        int fsize = 5000;
        int bsize = 5000;
        int fp;
        int bp;
        int x,y;
        Deque()
        {

            front.resize(fsize);
            back.resize(bsize);
            fp=-1;
            bp=-1;
            x=0;
            y=0;
        }
        void pushfront(int x)
        {
            if(fp>=fsize)
            {
                fsize = 2*fsize;
                front.resize(fsize);
            }
            fp++;    
            front[fp]=x;


        }
        void pushback(int x)
        {
            if(bp>=bsize)
            {
                bsize = 2*bsize;
                back.resize(bsize);
            }
            bp++;
            back[bp]=x;


        }
        r_vecitr f_begin()
        {
            return front.rbegin() + (front.end()-(front.begin()+fp+1));
        }
        r_vecitr f_end()
        {
            return front.rend();
        }
        vecitr b_begin()
        {
            return back.begin();
        }
        vecitr b_end()
        {
            return back.begin()+bp+1;
        }
       int getfront()
        {
            if(fp==0)
                return back[x];
            else if(fp-1>=0)
            return front[fp-1];
            else
            {
                return back[x++];
            }

        }
        int getback()
        { 
            if(bp-1>=0)
                return back[bp-1];
            else
                return front[y++];
        }
        void popfront()
        {
            if(fp>0)
            fp--;
        }
        void popback()
        {
            if(bp>0)
            bp--;
        }
        void cleard()
        {
            fp=-1;
            bp=-1;
        }
        int size()
        {
            return ( fp+bp +2 );
        }
        int empty()
        {
            if(fp+bp+2>0)
            return 0;
            else
            return 1;
        }
```

Comment: *std :: deque is slow* -- Let's see your proof of this.  You can't just say something is "slow" without proving it is.  Maybe your testing is flawed?  Are you timing a "release" optimized build, or an unoptimized "debug" build?

Comment: For simple push and pop operations std::deque is slow. I tested with over 10 million such operations. I guess the reason is std:: deque implements various checks on size and bounds for every operation. In my code I don't pop on a empty deque plus I know how much the size of my deque will grow so I need a very simple implementation that does the job. And yes I did compiled and tested with optimizations enabled.

Comment: *I guess the reason is std:: deque implements various checks on size and bounds for every operation.* -- No it doesn't.  Accessing a `std::deque` out-of-bounds using `[ ]` results in undefined behavior.  There is no checking for that operation.

Comment: Most of my acess is using back() and front(). Are they slow as compared to [ ] ?

Comment: front() does no error checking, and neither does back().  You have an empty deque and call either one, all bets are off.  So no checking is done internally by `std::deque`.  Bounds checking is done with the `at()` member function.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. But, as far as I observed pushing and poping elements and accessing elements for above implementation was way faster than deque<int>. Moreover, I also clear the deques before using them again. I ran a loop and put these 4 operations inside it for my deque class and std::deque and std::deque took twice the time. Which operation might be causing the slow down?

Comment: Show the full sample of your check with `std::deque` and the timings you are seeing.   You could also go to [this site](http://quick-bench.com/) and run your code.